# Get port of asp.net website without using HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a testbed for a RESTful API and I need to find a way to get the port number of the website in C# without using HttpContext.Request. The API and Testbed are in the same solution (and therefore can use similar code) and the testbed will always run on http://127.0.0.1, but the port may change.

Every answer I've found uses HttpContext.Request, but this does not work as there is not an inbound request at the code, and I cannot figure out a way to  garuntee that a request has happened (and therefore cached) before the code is called.

I would be open to using HttpContext.Request if I could be certain that there is a way to generate the request.

Comment: I don't quite understand the comment about request, how does one consume the api if not with a request? It's a restful web api right?

Comment: It is. The product calls the testbed via a url which is always on localhost. The problem is that I cannot be sure which port the product runs on for testing, so I do not know what the full url of the testbed is. Our policy is that the website must be able to run on any port to avoid clashing with other websites and products.

Comment: The port number should be a line in the web.config file. When it changes, you just update the config file.

Comment: Sadly I need to do this dynamically. However, I'll explore the possability.